# split column if variable number of pieces data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I want to split column `y` of `df` below according to the '_' but my data is incomplet. (`df` is just a representative portion of a bigger `data.frame`).

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = c("vuh_ftu_yefq", "sos_nvtspb", "pfymm_ucms",
                       "tucbexcqzh", "n_zndbhoun", "wdetzaolvn",
                       "lvohrpdqns", "wso_bsqwvr", "wx_gbkbxjl",
                       "t_dbxkkvge"))
```

I have tried using:

```
df$z <- strsplit(df$y,'_')
```

But I get an error because the number of pieces in each list are different.

How can I do this?

Comment: What should happen with the cells that do not contain an underscore '_' ?

Comment: You shouldn't get any error. You should get a new column of type `list`. What error message are you getting? I think you should try reading it. In other words, does `df$z <- strsplit(as.character(df$y),'_')` works? Though the real question is: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumptions:

- `)` needed to close out df in your example.
- `incomplete data` means it's filled in from the left such that a value without intervening '_' is the first or datum.

#### `tidyr`'s `separate()`:

```
result <- separate(df, y, into = c("z1","z2","z3") , sep ='_', extra = "drop")
```

- the key here is `extra = "drop"` which according to docs *always returns length(into) pieces by dropping or expanding as necessary*.

#### `data.table`'s `tstrsplit()`

```
DT <- as.data.table(df)
result <- DT[, c("z1", "z2","z3") := tstrsplit(y, '_', fixed=TRUE)][]
```

- the default behaviour for `tstrsplit()` does what you need and the `fixed=TRUE` is to pass to `strsplit()` underneath to keep things hasty.

*note: if your incomplete data is filled from the right you need to unmix your variables here!!!*

Comment: thank you this works but i had to install tidyr and data.table

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `separate` function from `tidyr`.

```
# required package
require(tidyr)
# separate (removing the y column)
separate(df, y, paste0("z", 1:3), sep = "_", extra = "merge")
# separate without removing the y column
separate(df, y, paste0("z", 1:3), sep = "_", extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you i wonder when merge and drop would be different outputs. though

Comment: If you only specify 2 columns, z1 and z2, then drop will just drop the 3rd column and merge will merge the 3rd column to the 2nd one. So if you specify the right number of columns, there should not be a difference.